# Launching Python script including Paho-mqtt library in RPi rc.local

Tags: python, mqtt, paho

I have installed Paho-mqtt python libray by "pip3 install paho-mqtt" on my RPi which I use for home automation purposes.
I made a python script to regulate my heatpump.
My script:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

"""
Programme de régulation de température


"""


import time
import json
import requests
from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth
import paho.mqtt.subscribe as subscribe
import paho.mqtt.publish as publish

#***********Récupération de l'état d'un élément de Domoticz***********

def dom_elmt(idx, valeur):
    url= 'http://127.0.0.1/json.htm?type=devices&rid='
    adresse= url+idx
    r=requests.get(adresse)
    status=r.status_code
    if status == 200:
    # l'API renvoie 200 si tout est OK
        getinfos=r.json()
        for i, v in enumerate(getinfos["result"]):
    #Récupération de la donnée "Status" du switch
            result= getinfos["result"][i][valeur]
    return result
#***********FIN Récupération de l'état du clavier************

#*********** 

Prev_Setpoint = 0

while True:

    msg = subscribe.simple("zigbee2mqtt/Thermo-Hygro Salle", hostname="127.0.0.1")
    y = json.loads(msg.payload)
    Temp = y["temperature"]
    print(time.strftime('%H:%M:%S', time.localtime()) ,"Température salle : ",Temp)

    #******** lecture du point de consigne idx: 230 ************
    Consigne=dom_elmt('230', "SetPoint")
    Consigne=float(Consigne)

    if Temp > Consigne + 0.2:
        Setpoint = Consigne - 0.5
    if Temp >= Consigne - 0.2 and Temp <= Consigne + 0.2:
        Setpoint = Consigne
    if Temp < Consigne - 0.2:
        Setpoint = Consigne + 0.5
        
    Setpoint = str(Setpoint)            # Transformation d'un float en str
    if Setpoint != Prev_Setpoint:       # Le point de consigne calculé est différent du précédent
        a = "{"
        b = '"temperature"'
        c = ":"
        d = "}"
        sendtemp = a+b+c+Setpoint+d
        
        publish.single("heatpump/set", sendtemp, hostname="127.0.0.1")
        Prev_Setpoint = Setpoint        # Mise à jour de Prev_Setpoint
```

If I launch this script on a console it works perfectly. I need but I can't launch it at boot in the rc.local.

```
....
if [ "$_IP" ]; then
  printf "My IP address is %s\n" "$_IP"
fi

python /home/pi/thermostat.py &

exit 0
```

This don't work and I don't understand what happen ?! (I launched other scripts in rc.local whithout any problem)
Does someone has an idea to help me ???
Thanks in advancecd

Answer (score 0):

This is because the python script will get killed when the script that started it exits even if it is pushed to the background with `&`.

The hacky solution is to prefix the command with `nohup` (which means the process will not get sent the Hang Up signal when the parent script exits).

The better option would be to write a proper systemd service [definition](https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-write-a-simple-systemd-service) for your script.

Comment: I tried systemd service without success. I also tried nohup without success either. Launching a script with infinite loop at boot seems to be very difficult ?!?!

Comment: Also this is a Linux question not really a Python/MQTT question, you should probably ask in on Unix/Linux or SuperUser

Comment: On second thought, this is not an infinite loop problem. For test I wrote a small script, a blinker that controls a virtual Domoticz switch by JSON. Started by rc.local with the & parameter, it works without problem.
(Really annoying the Stackflow editor)